# OS X Yosemite : cannot brew install imagemagick on Yosemite : libtool-2.4.6 error?

Tags: imagemagick, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Trying to install imagemagick ( to be used w PaperClip gem) on my mac ( Yosemite 10.10.5) raising error with 'libtool' what happen with it ?

```
    $ brew update

    $ brew install imagemagick
    ==> Installing dependencies for imagemagick: libtool, jpeg, libpng, libti
    ==> Installing imagemagick dependency: libtool
    ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libtool-2.4.6.yosemite.bott
    curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.
    Error: Failed to download resource "libtool"
    Download failed: https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libtool-2.4.6.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
    Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
    ==> Downloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.xz
    curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.
    Trying a mirror...
    ==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.xz
    curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.
    Error: Failed to download resource "libtool"
    Download failed: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.xz
```

Comment: Have you downloaded, installed and updated Xcode commandline tools?

Comment: I guess there is a recent upload of XCode ... I may have to update the CL tool ... checking thanks ...

Comment: that's it .. OS X was updated , however I forgot to update the CL Tool... thanks for putting me on tracks...

Comment: even after OS X CL update , no way same error message  with brew install imagemagick

ownloading http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.xz
curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.
Trying a mirror...
==> Downloading https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libtool/libtool-2.4.6.tar.xz
curl: (4) A requested feature, protocol or option was not found built-in in this libcurl due to a build-time decision.

Comment: I found a package at http://cactuslab.com/imagemagick/
it installs  imagemagick into /opt , then added the bin into $PATH... now running

Comment: Have you got any environment variables related to SSL Certificates?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error and https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/43154 fixed it for me. You will need to remove `SSL_CERT_DIR` variable from `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` and you might also need to run `unset SSL_CERT_DIR`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the homebrew-directory (~/Library/Caches/Homebrew) had root as owner. So executing

> sudo chown -R {myUserName}:staff Homebrew

fixed this issue and Homebrew worked again as expected.